# VS C++ application leaving background process open

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got a VS c++ project using SFML that I'm working on but every time i close the program it leaves a background process open after the project has been exited.[image of task manager here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZIqC.png)

I know roughly why this is happening but haven't found any other articles online with this issue. This issue started popping up after i started closing the console window upon startup of my program. In an attempt to remedy this (since i no longer need the console window anyways) I've tried to convert the project to a windows application, but the problem is persisting, I'll include the code in my main, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "gameStates/StateStack.h"


using namespace std;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    bool close = false;
    StateStack game;

    do
    {
        game.handleEvents();
        game.update();
        game.draw();

    }while(!close);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bool close = false; /*...*/ do { /*...*/ } while(!close);` This is an infinite loop, since none of the code that I edited out changes `close`.

Comment: @dxiv ...............that moment when you've been staring something for hours and you cant see the simple solution. Thanks man. Time to go beat my head on a brick. :p

Comment: No worry, and don't punish your head. It gets better with time ;-)